# iOS XMPP never receives any friend / roster requests

Tags: ios, xmpp

## Setup

I'm sending a friend / roster request using this code:

```
[[[XMPPController sharedObject] roster] addUser:[XMPPJID jidWithString:[user stringByAppendingString:@"@server.com"]] withNickname:nil];
```

and I can confirm that in the ejabberd Web Admin control panel, the request is sent. Also, the request is returned in the stream delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq
```

as confirmation.

I've read across multiple questions here that the request should be handled in the delegate method:

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence
```

alternatively

```
- (void)xmppRoster:(XMPPRoster *)sender didReceivePresenceSubscriptionRequest:(XMPPPresence *)presence
```

## The Issue

The issue is that neither of these methods get called once a request is send.

## Tested on

- iPhone 5 (iOS 9.3.1)
- iPhone Simulator (iOS 9.3)

Sending from either devices yields no success.

## Notes

I can confirm that the friend request is send, because it is visible in the ejabberd admin panel. Additionally, if a user is added from the admin panel, nothing happens on the client side (The one that should receive the request, that is.).

Answer (score 2):

The method `- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence` or `- (void)xmppRoster:(XMPPRoster *)sender didReceivePresenceSubscriptionRequest:(XMPPPresence *)presence`
 are not being called because you are not sending any`XMPPPresence`.

Comment: I'm sending presence using `XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presence]; [self.stream sendElement:presence];` inside `- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender `. Is it the correct way to do it?

Comment: You should send the presence when you send the buddy request ! It should work then

Comment: I tried putting the code both before and after (and both) I send the buddy request, but I still got no response from the other side

Comment: Your server has to also send a presence object if you want to receive one

Comment: How can I check / enable that?

Comment: It's server side, so you can go through you server's code

Comment: Yes but what exactly do I need to change in my server's code?